# can my isp read my emails or see whom i send/receive emails from?

Tags: email, isp

can my Isp read my emails or see whom I send emails or receive emails from? i use rediffmail.com, Gmail and outlook.com for emails. All are https and I use cloudeflare dns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use your ISP as mail provider but instead a mail provider fully independent from your ISP, the mails are at least not directly stored by the ISP and thus can not be read there. If you exclusively access the mail providers with HTTPS (i.e. web based mail access) then the ISP can also only see that you use the mail provider, but not the data you exchange.

This of course assumes that no man in the middle with HTTPS by the ISP is possible, i.e. that you don't skip any browser warnings regarding encryption and that you don't have any ISP controlled certificate authorities installed as trusted. A problem here might also local parental or antivirus software, which often does local HTTPS interception - some products failed in the past to properly check upstream certificates which would allow the ISP to do HTTPS interception without warnings. And of course, don't run any software on your system which comes from a party you don't trust and which might work together with your ISP.

If instead you are using a mail program which communicates with the mail provider using SMTP (to send mails), POP3 or IMAP (to get mails), then there might be a way for the ISP to infer with the connection and read the mail. Unless you mail program enforces encryption with these protocols they might either be used without encryption by configuration, or because the ISP infers with the traffic to enforce no encryption. Also sometimes encryption is used by mail programs but certificates are not properly checked, in which case the ISP might to a TLS man in the middle attack.

Comment: Tyvm sir. much appreciated.